# When creating a folder in Google Drive, it returns an error 401 login reguired, LARAVEL

Tags: google-drive-api

although it works locally, but not on the server, but it worked fine a month ago
I use package nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive

```
"errors"[
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],"code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include your code.  or just authorize your application again.   Remember oauth2 playground is only for testing,  not for production.  Your application should be authorizing your code internally your access tokens are going to be expiring within a week if you dont.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.